# CASE WHEN - LIKE - REGEXP in Hadoop Hive

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, case, rlike

I want to write a query in a hive Table using CASE WHEN, LIKE and a regular expression. I have used `regexp` and `rlike`, but I do not get the desired results. My attempts so far are the following

```
    select distinct ending from
(select date, ending, name, count(distinct id) 
from (select CONCAT_WS("/",year,month,day,hour) as date, id, name,
case when type = 'TRAN' then 'tran'
when events regexp '%[:]no_reply[:]%[^o][^n][:]incomplete[:]%' and type rlike '%HUP' then 'con'
when events not regexp '%[:]no_reply[:]%[^o][^n][:]incomplete[:]%' and type rlike '%HUP'  then 'aban'
else 'other'
end as ending
from data_struct1) tmp
group by date, ending, name) tmp2;
```

and also

```
select distinct ending from
    (select date, ending, name, count(distinct id) 
    from (select CONCAT_WS("/",year,month,day,hour) as date, id, name,
    case when type = 'TRAN' then 'tran'
    when events rlike '%[:]no_reply[:]%[^o][^n][:]incomplete[:]%' and type rlike '%HUP' then 'con'
    when events not rlike '%[:]no_reply[:]%[^o][^n][:]incomplete[:]%' and type rlike '%HUP'  then 'aban'
    else 'other'
    end as ending
    from data_struct1) tmp
    group by date, ending, name) tmp2;
```

Both queries return incorrect results (not bad syntax, just not the correct results).

Comment: what are you trying to do, please describe, the regex are definitely wrong. What this '%[:]no_reply[:]%[^o][^n][:]incomplete[:]%' should do?

Comment: the regexp is the following: `'\:no_reply\:[^:]*\:incomplete\:\:'`

Comment: Just tell what should it do. Your regex seems wrong again. You do not heed slash before `:`, but I'm not sure what regex really should do. Provide string example if possible

Comment: In this string: `opencase_2,initial_state:inquiry,inquiry:no_reply:initial_state:incomplete::,inquiry:reask:secondary_state:complete::`
I need to check whether I have the following substring:
`no_reply:initial_state:incomplete`, however, the string in the middle `initial_state` can vary between a lot of values (300 different ones, meaning I can not write exhaustive if conditions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of docs on regex quantifiers, for example this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions

```
select 'opencase_2,initial_state:inquiry,inquiry:no_reply:initial_state:incomplete::,inquiry:reask:secondary_state:complete::' regexp 'no_reply:[^:]+:incomplete';

OK
true
```

Also this is wrong: `rlike '%HUP'`. It should be like this `'.*HUP$'` (in the end of the string) or simply 'HUP' if it does not matter where the HUP is located: in the middle or in the end or in the beginning of the string

`rlike` and `regexp` in your query work the same, better use the same operator: regexp or rlike only. These two are synonyms.

Test: https://regex101.com/r/ksG67v/1